# Play .mp3 UWP with storage Folder

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to make a small project. Something like a soundboard with jokes from work. But i can´t play sounds in UWP. I found this:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Button_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MediaElement PlayMusic = new MediaElement();
            PlayMusic.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.Media;
            StorageFolder Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            Folder = await Folder.GetFolderAsync("folder");
            StorageFile sf = await Folder.GetFileAsync("song.mp3");
            PlayMusic.SetSource(await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), sf.ContentType);
            PlayMusic.Play();
        }`
```

but i dont know where I have to put the sound.
I have tried the Assets folder but it didn´t work. 
Im a newbie and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You can select your file to play using **FileOpenPicker** or you can place your file in assets folder and access using uri. Added both sample code snippet below

//Play from file

```
private async void PlayFromFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Play from file
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4p");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        var sf = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(sf);
        mediaPlayer.Play();           
    }
```

//Play from assets folder

```
 private void PlayFromAssetsFolder(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Play from assets folder
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/audio.mp3"));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
```

Comment: and how can i play different audios for different buttons?

Comment: Keep your files in assets folder and place the uri in Tag of your listviewitem. Receive it on buttonclick the play that particular uri

Comment: If you want to play multiple audio files mention it in question .

Comment: See [Background media playback sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback). It can play a collection of songs or videos even when the app is no longer in the foreground.